# Cypress how to return JWT token from localstorage and use it in another api call

Tags: jwt, token, cypress

Hi What I am trying to do is to save the localStorage in to variable somewhere , So i can refer to it in different test scenario but I am not sure if that is possible as my token1 variable is always empty.

this is my support/command.js file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('postTokenLogin', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '***/people/sign_in',
        body: {
            "login": "test@test.com",
            "password":"***",     
        },
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.body).have.property('firstName')
        expect(response.body.token).have.property('authorization')
        cy.setLocalStorage('token',response.body.token.authorization )
    })
})
```

now in my test case I wanna be able to use that token inside my header

```
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
    let token1 = '';
    describe('HTTP Example', ()=>{
        before(() => {
            cy.postTokenLogin();
            cy.saveLocalStorage();
          });
        beforeEach(() => {
            cy.restoreLocalStorage();
          });

        it("the value of JWT Token should exist in localStorage", () => {
            cy.getLocalStorage('token').then(token => {
              cy.log("the token", token); // I get JWT Token in here
            });
          });
        it('GET List ', ()=>{
            
            cy.getLocalStorage('token').then((token) => {
                token1 = token;
              })
              cy.log('Let Tokennn is ===>' , token1) // Always Empty
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '***/peopleList',
    headers:{
        'content-type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': token1 // ===> this is also empty
    }
}).then((response) => {
    expect(response.body).have.property('firstName')
    expect(response.body).have.property('lastname')
})
        })
    })
```

Can I have another  it('GET colours ', ()=>{}) and just pass the token1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in a async code, so if you need to use the token instead of validation, you should nest the code like below

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
let token1 = '';
describe('HTTP Example', () => {
      before(() => {
        cy.postTokenLogin();
        cy.saveLocalStorage();
      });
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
      });

      it("the value of JWT Token should exist in localStorage", () => {
        cy.getLocalStorage('token').then(token => {
          cy.log("the token", token); // I get JWT Token in here
        });
      });
      it('GET List ', () => {

        cy.getLocalStorage('token').then((token) => {
          token1 = token;
          cy.log('Let Tokennn is ===>', token1) // Always Empty

          cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '***/peopleList',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': token1 // ===> this is also empty
            }
          }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.body).have.property('firstName')
            expect(response.body).have.property('lastname')
          })
        })

      })
```

Comment: thank you for the respond. how can I store that token somewhere, so I can use it anywhere else?

Comment: Dump it in file and read again https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile/#Text ` cy.writeFile('path/to/token.txt', 'tokenvalue')
cy.readFile('path/to/token.txt').then((token) => {
 ....
}) `

Comment: @RahulL thank you appreciated your answer is what I was looking for